# How to global StatusCode handling in blazor and show MudBlazor Snackbar

Tags: c#, blazor, http-status-code-404, snackbar, mudblazor

Is there a way to global business exception handling for both server asp.net web api and client blazor project and show exception message by MudBlazor Snackbar **automatically** instead of repeating Snackbar.Add when we get statuscode!=200?

Answer (score 1):

**ExceptionHandler** in server project:

```
public static class ExceptionHandler
{
    public static void AddExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(appError =>
        {
            appError.Run(async context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                var contextFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                if (contextFeature?.Error is AppException)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status409Conflict;
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(CheckException(contextFeature.Error));
                }
            });
        });
    }

    private static string CheckException(Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException is not null)
            return ex.Message + " - InnerException : " + ex.InnerException.Message;
        return ex.Message;
    }
}

public class AppException : Exception
{
    public AppException(string message) : base(message) { }
}
```

Add this extension method to program.cs of **server** project:

```
app.AddExceptionHandler(); // here
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
app.Run();
```

Use **AppException** in service classes:

```
public async Task<int> ConfirmEmail(Guid userId)
    {
        var user = await _db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);

        if (user is null)
            throw new AppException("This activate code is not valid");

        if (user.IsConfirm == true)
            throw new AppException("This account is activated before");

        user.IsConfirm = true;
        return await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Add **HttpStatusCodeService** class in **client** project:

```
public class HttpStatusCodeService : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ISnackbar _snackbar;
    private readonly NavigationManager _navigationManager;
    public HttpStatusCodeService(ISnackbar snackbar, NavigationManager navigationManager)
    {
        _snackbar = snackbar;
        _navigationManager = navigationManager;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // before sending the request
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // after sending the request
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict) // here
                _snackbar.Add(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), Severity.Warning);

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                _snackbar.Add("Server error , tell us please", Severity.Error);

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

install this **package** on **Client** project : **Microsoft.Extensions.Http**

**Inject** SnackbarService and HttpStatusCodeService by HttpClient in program.cs of **Client** project:

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

// MudBlazor
builder.Services.AddMudServices();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISnackbar, SnackbarService>();

// Add all Singleton AppServices
var appServices = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(s => s.Name.EndsWith("Service") && s.IsInterface == false).ToList();
foreach (var appService in appServices)
    builder.Services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(appService, appService, ServiceLifetime.Singleton));

// HttpClient
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("http", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress + "api/");
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<HttpStatusCodeService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("http"));

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Now use any api in blazor **components** or blazor **services**:

```
private async Task ConfirmEmail()
    {
        confirmEmailProcess = true;
        var httpResponseMessage = await http.PutAsync($"User/ConfirmEmail/{activateCode}", null);
        if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Snackbar.Add(@"Your email has been verified and your account has been successfully activated<br>
                          Now you can log in", Severity.Success);
            registerDialogVisible = false;
            activateCode = "";
            mudTabs.ActivePanelIndex = 0;
        }
        confirmEmailProcess = false;
    }
```